# Excel: How to sumif, if the data points share the same row?

Tags: excel-formula

How can I look up the column header and output the sum of values underneath the two columns but only if they share the same row. For example in my picture I want to sum under A and C which should output 2 since they share a 1 in both the top row and the bottom row. Again if I wanted the same formula for A and B it would output 0 as they share none of the same data points in the same row. Basically I want to pivot not numerical data and be able to  determine the total number of shared x values between my choice of y values.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMRPODUCT to count where the ranges returned by INDEX/MATCH are equal:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($A$2:$D$6,0,MATCH($F$2,$A$1:$D$1,0))<> "") *(INDEX($A$2:$D$6,0,MATCH($F$2,$A$1:$D$1,0))=INDEX($A$2:$D$6,0,MATCH($F$3,$A$1:$D$1,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: So this formula is outputting total similar values, therefore the 'A' column and 'D' column output 3 as they also share blanks. Is there anyway to filter out to only sum if 1? Therefore choosing A and D would output 1?

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Comment: SUMRPODUCT ? Is this the new xl2019 beta?